# Is it possible to password protect access to a folder with your macOS password?

Tags: security, permission

I'm trying to figure out the best place for me to backup my Lastpass CSV and it seems like the best place to put it would be on my full-disk-encrypted macbook, but I would like to be able to require a password before someone is actually able to read it.

I know I can password protect a folder with a chosen password but that's likely something that will be forgotten.

Is there a way to set the permissions of a file to require the Admin password before viewing the contents?

Comment: Why not just password protect it with your admin password? Then you won't forget the password (hopefully) ;)

Comment: You can save the file somewhere that normally is only accessible by the admin. The admin's Library/ folder, or if you are in fact the admin, then /var/root would work too.

Comment: I was hoping there was a simple permission set I could use, /var/root just says I don't have permission, /Library I can open right up with no prompts.

Answer (score 1):

You can always use Disk Image to mount an encrypted partition that you can write files to. You choose the password, so you could set it to be the same as the password for admin. It's pretty simple to do:

https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201599

Comment: But if I change my system password, which I do periodically, the password to that partition won't change. So if I'm storing things long-term in there that I access infrequently (like my backed up lastpass vault), odds are by the time I need it the password will be different than my system password.